# Connect to mysql with server provider using Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I have a database trough my server provider. I want to use PHP to connect to this database, and fetch the data with AJAX.

I have been in contact with the server provider, and they say that for a remote app to connect to the database and fetch data, I have to whitelist the IP adress first and then the app can connect to the database.

The problem here is that I do not know the IP adresses that will connect trough the app.

The code I have at the moment is just standard since I can't connect to the server provider.

```
$servername = "";
$username   = "";
$password   = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

Is there some other way I can connect to the server provider?
Or maybe set the application to use a default IP adress in the app?

I do not know how cordova handle this kinds of things and I guess the IP adress of the user is the one being sendt?

Best regards
JP

Comment: The IP address has nothing to do with Cordova or the application.  They're simply telling you that you need to know the IP of your web server and configure the database to allow connections from that web server.  You can get your IP from your web host.

Comment: Okey. So what I should do is to have my PHP connection script on my web-server and then use ajax in cordova to read that php file from my web server?